# -webkit-mask-image is not working in sass

Tags: css, sass, gulp, node-sass, image-masking

I'm using Gulp (node-sass) for compiling sass files to css.

I've added `-webkit-mask-image` in my sass files like this:

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left 30%, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
```

but gulp compile it like this:

```
mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left 30%, left, right);
```

what am I doing wrong? is any way to add experimental css technologies in gulp(node-sass)?

Edit: I found the solution. I should describe value as a string and then set in `-webkit-mask-image`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should describe value as a string and then set in -webkit-mask-image.

```
$gradientSidebar: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left 30%, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)))";
.my-class{
   -webkit-mask-image: #{$mobileGradientSidebar};
}
```